# Can I enable barriers for ext4 under LVM?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext4

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and if I issue:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
```

I don't see `barrier=1` next to my main filesystem (under LVM). Does this mean barriers are not enabled? I read that while there were issues with this some time ago, now barriers are compatible with LVM.

If they are not enabled, how can I enable them? Maybe by adding the option in `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### They are enabled by default

Since many years ago, barriers are enabled by default on ext4. If you want to turn barriers *off* (and you have same sort of battery backup) then you can add `barrier=0` to the options field in `/etc/fstab`. See the [ext 4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) on kernel.org.

Generally speaking, don't add options to fstab unless you have a good reason; the defaults are safe and well thought.

Comment: So to get this right, it's normal for barrier=1 to not be there because it's not mentioned as it's a default? Thanks

Comment: Yes. If you set `barrier=0` then it will appear as it would be a non-default setting.